# How to know if sender requested receipt?

Tags: gmail

You can see whether a person has read your email by requesting a receipt.

However, as the recipient of the mail, is there any way to tell whether the sender has requested a receipt or not?

This question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/642574/how-do-i-know-if-an-email-had-a-read-receipt-and-how-does-this-affect-my-differe), but for Gmail.

On their [website](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1385059), it says you can configure this from the 'administrator', but is that only for the 'Business, Education, and Government customers' or is that for personal users too?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Google FAQ: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1385059?rd=1

[image: Read Receipts Request in GMail]

When you receive a message for which a user has requested a read receipt, Gmail may automatically send the receipt or may ask you to approve sending the receipt.

To approve a read receipt, follow these directions:

- Open and read the message as usual while using the desktop version of Gmail at mail.google.com.
- When you close the message or navigate away from it, you will be prompted to send a read receipt.
- Read Receipts Requested
- Click Send receipts or Not now.
- If you click Not now, you will be prompted again the next time you open this conversation.

Comment: Yes. Your link is the one I provided in the question. But it states at the beginning 'Read receipts are available only for Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government customers. They are not available in personal Gmail accounts.' Does that mean the option to allow/deny read receipts is not available for personal accounts?

Comment: I think this is correct. This applies to GMail webclient only of-course, as there is no reason why it would not work if you are using external email client.